# Is adding a transition to nearly every element a bad practice?

Tags: css, sass

In web tech,

If I were to add the following lines of code to my stylesheet, would I be essentially adding a lot of heavy work for all elements of these where nearly no visual effects will be seen on the front end?

I want elements to animate when a resize of their width/height is done.

```
p, h1, h2, h3, h4, img, div {
    @include transition(all 0.3s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Transition/Animation will add some **overload** to browser as compared to plain site as `left`, `top`, `margin`, `padding`, etc causes the browser to recalculate styles every frame.

You should read the article of [CSS and JavaScript animation performance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Fundamentals/Performance/CSS_JavaScript_animation_performance) and [CSS animations and transitions performance](http://blogs.adobe.com/webplatform/2014/03/18/css-animations-and-transitions-performance/)